# HDR sky not showing on preview or on render

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to add a HDR sky and it's not showing when I preview render, or in the final render.

I did everything I could, like press number 5 and check transparent. Can someone help me?

Comment: How did you add it?

Comment: Hi there :) Please attach an image of the world setting panel and your render

Comment: In the Render tab on the RHS (looks like a camera), scroll through until you see a checkbox for "Transparent". Make sure it is UNCHECKED.

I assume you remember how to access the World shader. (at the top of the Node Editor there is a dropdown that says "Object" (as in a scene object) by default, change it to "World"). Go there in the Node Editor. You should have 3 nodes: [Environment Texture] --> [Background] --> [World Output (In: Surface)].